# Format String : Parsing

Tags: c#, .net, parsing

I have a parsing question.  I have a paragraph which has instances of `:  word`  . So basically it has a colon, two spaces, a word (could be anything), then two more spaces.

So when I have those instances I want to convert the string so I have

1. A new line character after `:` and the word.
2. Removed the double space after the word.
3. Replace all double spaces with new line characters.

Don't know exactly how about to do this.  I'm using C# to do this. Bullet point 2 above is what I'm having a hard time doing this.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want to do with the spaces between the `:` and the word?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
var str = ":  first  :  second  ";
var result = Regex.Replace(str, ":\\s{2}(?<word>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\s{2}",
                                                         ":\n${word}\n");
```

Comment: Oooh that's neat. I like this. Except I had to change out the `\\s` to just spaces to get the proper matches.

Comment: Thanks for the post. What does this exactly do?  Does it do 1-3 from above.

Comment: It will replace any occurrence of ':  word  ' with a newline after the colon, and a newline after the word. No double spaces around the word

Comment: It tried this one out, did not work. Zhais you were saying to replace \\s with space in the regular expression. So i just put a space " " instead of "\\s"? Wait i'm guessing that is just \s. I think I just answered my own question.

Comment: Oh i replace \\s with \s, I need the extra \ to escape \s.

Comment: @Hitesh yes the regex expression has to be `\s` so the extra slash is required; it has to be `\\s` or you can use a verbatim string like this `@":\s{2}(?<word>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\s{2}"`

Comment: How do I make it so that a-zA-Z0-9 includes any characters meaning . (period), *, etc?

Comment: That worked thanks.  Also I noticed at times after the word there is sometimes only one space. Curious how can I can I change this :\\s{2}(?<word>[a-zA-Z0-9]+)\\s{2} so it checks for both instances.  So change s{2} so it checks for one space or two spaces.

Comment: @Hitesh `{1,2}` instead of `{2}`

Comment: [a-zA-Z0-9.*] That worked for a .,but it did not pick up -.  Ex. Left-sided would not work.

Comment: I guess that expression is anything but space. I noticed its not picking up characters like \, -, commas. From the ones I'm seeing.  I guess its anything but a space.  Ex. of things not working: "left-sided", "fever,", "john\doe", and "Comparison:".

Comment: Oh i figured it out.  I replace it with [^\\s].  So anything but a space.

Comment: Thanks for all your help.  This was the final solution I used. Regex.Replace(stry, ":\\s{1}(?<word>[^\\s]+)\\s{1,2}", ":\n${word} ").Replace(" ", "\n");

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your original string is exactly in the form you described, this will do:

```
var newString = myString.Trim().Replace("  ", "\n");
```

The [`Trim()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) removes leading and trailing whitespaces, taking care of your spaces at the end of the string.

Then, the [`Replace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/czx8s9ts.aspx) replaces the remaining `"  "` two space characters, with a `"\n"` new line character.

The result is assigned to the `newString` variable. This is needed, as `myString` will not change - as strings in .NET are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object).

I suggest you read up on the [`String`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1wwdcbf.aspx) class and all its methods and properties.

Comment: You would have to use a regex to isolate these instances of mystring from the paragraph first, if I've understood the question correctly

Comment: A blanket trim and replace will give a lot of unwanted results... This definitely is not the solution that Hitesh is looking for.

Comment: Zhais you are correct.  There is a third part, which I thought was not that important to include but now that I think about it does matter.  I added that above.  I was thinking some type of regular expression.  Anybody good at doing those? Also this is a paragraph that has multiple instances of this stuff.

Comment: I set up a good start in an answer below. If you give a more detailed example of the before and after strings that you are looking for, I can make it a bit more detailed

Answer (score 2):

Using RegularExpressions will give you exact matches on what you are looking for.

The regex match for a colon, two spaces, a word, then two more spaces is:

```
Dim reg as New Regex(":    [a-zA-Z]*    ")
```

`[a-zA-Z]` will look for any character within the alphabetical range. Can append `0-9` on as well if you accept numbers within the word. The `*` afterwards indicated that there can be 0 or more instances of the preceding value.

`[a-zA-Z]*` will attempt to do a full match of any set of contiguous alpha characters.

Upon further reading, you may use `[\w]` in place of `[a-zA-Z0-9]` if that's what you are looking for. This will match any 'word' character.

source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx

You can retrieve all the matches using `reg.Matches(inputString)`.

Review http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx for more information on regular expression replacements and your options from there out

edit: Before I was using `\s` to search for spaces. This will match any whitespace character including tabs, new lines and other. That is not what we want, so I reverted it back to search for exact space characters.

Comment: Thanks for the post I will try it out and let you know how it works out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use string.TrimEnd - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trimend.aspx - to trim spaces at the end of the string.

Comment: Well that would not work, because ":  word  " appears in the paragraph multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

The following is an example using Regular Expressions. See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3935008/c-regex-replace-getting-the-values) for more info.

Basically the pattern string tells the regex to look for a colon followed by two spaces. Then we save in a capture group named "word" whatever the word is surrounded by two spaces on either side. Finally two more spaces are specified to finish the pattern.

The replace uses a lambda which says for every match, replace it with a colon, a new line, the "lone" word, and another newline.

```
string Paragraph = "Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz:  fizz  The quick onyx goblin jumps over the lazy dwarf. Where:  buzz  The crazy dogs.";
string Pattern = @":  (?<word>\S*)  ";
string Result = Regex.Replace(Paragraph, Pattern, m =>
    {
        var LoneWord = m.Groups[1].Value;
         return @":" + Environment.NewLine + LoneWord + Environment.NewLine;
    },
    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

**Input**

```
Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz:  fizz  The quick onyx goblin jumps over the lazy dwarf. Where:  buzz  The crazy dogs.
```

**Output**

```
Jackdaws love my big sphinx of quartz:
fizz
The quick onyx goblin jumps over the lazy dwarf. Where:
buzz
The quick brown fox.
```

Note, for item 3 on your list, if you also want to replace individual occurrences of two spaces with newlines, you could do this:

```
Result = Result.Replace("  ", Environment.NewLine);
```

Comment: Using your code from above. What does "m =>" mean.  Is this .net? Maybe it was not translated proper after you posted. I'm using C# VS 2005

Comment: The `m =>` is the [lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) - basically it is an anonymous method that means for every match, we'll name the variable `m`. Using that variable, call the method enclosed in brackets.

Comment: Interesting, did not know you can do that.  Thanks.